# Is It bad for performance if a bunch of threads are in a blocking state?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, bsd, openbsd

Does the Linux or BSD kernel slow down if a program has a bunch of threads in a blocking io state, or is the performance deficit so negligible that it can be ignored. I am writing a server program that will handle ~7000 clients and am wondering how bad the performance hit would be if 1000 of those clients just idled for 2 hours. I am using a basic consumer machine that will run Debian Linux or OpenBSD BSD.

I am using C and C++.

Comment: No, blocked threads have practically no overhead.

Comment: There's the memory consumed, but CPU performance would not be affected. The scheduler has no reason to routinely inspect/review the suspended queues. The kernel is primarily event driven rather than polled.

Comment: Make sure you do not run out of file descriptors with all these connected clients.  IMHO idle for 2 hours should have been disconnected by some timeout, and asked to connect again.

Answer (score 0):

If those threads are waiting for an event most of the time, there are no drawbacks except, of course, some memory eing eaten. E.g., each (kernel) thread has its own stack, which is 4..16 MB usually on modern amd64 systems. Unless you're starting a thread for each of the 7000 clients you have, there will be no problems: kernel won't touch those threads at all while some I/O or signal won't happen there.

If you really plan to have 7000 kernel threads... you'd better not. Please look at non-blocking I/O, in particular, the good starting point will be the portable [poll(2)](https://man.openbsd.org/poll.2) API. This is what much of modern high-performance software like nginx uses under the hood to handle a lot of network clients simultaneously.